# The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers: Test_Login.Controllers.HomeController BPF.Controllers.HomeController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Please Help, I get an error like this

**Server Error in '/' Application.**
Multiple types were found that match the controller named '`Home`'. This can happen if the route that services this request `('{controller}/{action}/{id}')` does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the '`MapRoute`' method that takes a '`namespaces`' parameter.

The request for '`Home`' has found the following matching controllers:

```
User_Login_MVC.Controllers.HomeController

BPF.Controllers.HomeController
```

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details**: `System.InvalidOperationException`: Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This can happen if the route that services this request `('{controller}/{action}/{id}')` does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:

```
User_Login_MVC.Controllers.HomeController

BPF.Controllers.HomeController
```

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

[**InvalidOperationException**: Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This can happen if the route that services this request `('{controller}/{action}/{id}')` does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the '`MapRoute`' method that takes a '`namespaces`' parameter.

The request for '`Home`' has found the following matching controllers:

```
User_Login_MVC.Controllers.HomeController

BPF.Controllers.HomeController]
```

> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerTypeWithinNamespaces(RouteBase route, String controllerName, HashSet`1 namespaces) +159
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerType(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +544
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory.GetControllerSessionBehavior(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +53
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetSessionStateBehavior(RequestContext requestContext) +132
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) +33
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) +10
>      System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +9966527
>      System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +82
>      System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +141
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +71

and this my Code HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace BPF.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Profile()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index(User user)
        {
            UsersEntities usersEntities = new UsersEntities();
            int? userId = usersEntities.ValidateUser(user.Username, user.Password).FirstOrDefault();

            string message = string.Empty;
            switch (userId.Value)
            {
                case -1:
                    message = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                    break;
                case -2:
                    message = "Account has not been activated.";
                    break;
                default:
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, user.RememberMe);
                    return RedirectToAction("Profile");
            }

            ViewBag.Message = message;
            return View(user);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

This My Code RouteConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace BPF
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                //namespaces: new[] { "RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, MVC cannot support two actions with the same name… even
>   with differents signatures. The only exception is when one of the
>   actions is decorated with a different HTTP VERB attribute, like – for
>   example – [HttpGet]  for the former and [HttpPost]  for the latter:

and your first method, probably have the default verb "HttpPost"